# How to only accept two kinds of email domain in form?

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I have a form and one of the input fields ask the user to input their email. However, I only want to accept @gmail.com and @outlook.com but my code only seems to accepts @outlook.com.  Can anyone give some advice on my code?

```
    $( "#email" ).change(function() {
    if (this.value.length <= 0 ) {
        email=0;
        $(this).removeClass( 'success_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'error_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "You need to enter your email";
    } else if (this.value.length > 200) {
        email=0;
        $(this).removeClass( 'success_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'error_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "The email is too big.";
    } else if ((this.value.search('@outlook.com') == -1 || this.value.search('@gmail.com') == -1) || (this.value.length != this.value.search('@outlook.com')+12 ||this.value.length != this.value.search('@gmail.com')+10)) {
        email=0;
        $(this).removeClass( 'success_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'error_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "You must enter your Gmail or Outlook email";
    } else {
        email=1;
        $(this).removeClass( 'error_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'success_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: You could add a `select` tag that includes only those two options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you are checking for these domains. Look at this line:

```
else if ((this.value.search('@outlook.com') == -1 || this.value.search('@gmail.com') == -1)
```

Let's see what happens when someone enters '@gmail.com'. The first condition checking for the absence of '@outlook.com' returns true, and the code block is entered, without checking for '@gmail.com'. So it appears to not work.

Few ways you could fix this:

1) use a positive search result instead of negative.

```
if(this.value.search('@outlook.com') > -1 || this.value.search('@gmail.com') > -1) {
// code for correctly entered email
}
```

2) use a Regular Expression. From Sagar V's answer, a good one to use is:

```
/\@(gmail|outlook)\.com$/i
```

3) use a select box that forces the user to pick one domain. This isn't good UI/UX in my opinion because users may not be familiar with entering an email like this, and would probably type it all into your input anyway.

I would prefer the regular expression as it's easier to follow, when you understand what it's doing.

Comment: Appreciate your helpful advice.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use regex `/\@(gmail|outlook){1}\.com$/i` ->

- \@ should contain @
- (gmail|outlook) must have only one occurrence of gmail or outlook
- .com$ .com and end
- i -> flag case insensitive

```js
$( "#email" ).change(function() {
    if (this.value.length <= 0 ) {
        email=0;
        $(this).removeClass( 'success_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'error_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "You need to enter your email";
    } else if (this.value.length > 200) {
        email=0;
        $(this).removeClass( 'success_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'error_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "The email is too big.";
    } else if (!/\@(gmail|outlook)\.com$/i.test(this.value)) {
        email=0;
        $(this).removeClass( 'success_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'error_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "You must enter your Gmail or Outlook email";
    } else {
        email=1;
        $(this).removeClass( 'error_class' );
        $(this).addClass( 'success_class' );
        document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
<div id="emailError"></div>
```

Comment: I would add `i` flag to the regex because `ME@GMAIL.COM` is a valid Gmail address.

Comment: Sure @Pavlo . Because the aim of SO as well as Our's is to provide quality answers. no matter from whom it is and who edited. :-)

Comment: Thanks Everyone :) . That was helpful.

Comment: marking as answer will help future visitors of this post

Comment: `{1}` seems redundant